# Haskell bzlib-conduit/zlib-conduit example

Tags: haskell, conduit, zlib-conduit, bzlib-conduit

Let's assume we create the file `a.txt.gz` as follows:

```
$ echo "foobar" > a.txt
$ gzip a.txt
```

I intend to use [`zlib-conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-conduit) in order to emulate `zcat` in Haskell.

I'm looking for a simple example that can also be applied to [`bzlib-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bzlib-conduit).

*Note:* This question was answered immediately in a Q&A-Style. Therefore it intentionally does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to work with `conduit`s, I highly recommend to read the excellent [Conduit overview by Michael Snoyman](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview) and the [FP Complete tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/conduit-overview) on this topic first.

I've turned on my `-vv` flag to make this suitable for Haskell beginners (like myself).

You need three things:

- A file source
- A zlib decompression filter
- A stdout sink

Let's start off with this simple file copy example:

```hs
import Data.Conduit (runResourceT, ($$))
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import Data.Conduit.Zlib

main = do
    runResourceT $ CB.sourceFile "input.txt" $$ CB.sinkFile "output.txt"
```

What do we need to modify here?

- The input filename is not `a.txt.gz`
- zlib decompressor is missing
- We want to output to stdout, not to `output.txt`

Indeed the [`decompress` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-conduit-1.0.0/docs/Data-Conduit-Zlib.html#v%3adecompress) contains an example of how to decompress.

Note that you can't use `decompress` for `gzip`-generated files. `decompress` decompresses `.Z` files generated by the old `compress` UNIX program.

After modifying the above example we get:

```hs
import Data.Conduit (runResourceT, ($$), ($=))
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import Data.Conduit.Zlib
import System.IO

main = do
    runResourceT $ CB.sourceFile "a.txt.gz" $= ungzip $$ CB.sinkHandle stdout
```

The difference when using `bzlib-conduit` is minimal:

```
import Data.Conduit (runResourceT, ($$), ($=))
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import Data.Conduit.BZlib
import System.IO

main = do
    runResourceT $ CB.sourceFile "a.txt.bz2" $= bunzip2 $$ CB.sinkHandle stdout
```