# Ignoring subtrees in streaming xml-conduit

Tags: xml, haskell, xml-conduit

The [xml-conduit documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.2.0.2/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html) only lists examples where the entire XML tree is consumed by a `ConduitM`, for example:

```
<people>
    <person age="25">Michael</person>
    <person age="2">Eliezer</person>
</people>
```

I'm trying to parse a tree where besides the `<person>` tags from above, there are deeply nested subtrees I'm not interested in (their exact schema might even be unknown), for example:

```
<people>
    <person age="25">Michael</person>
    <tagImNotInterestedIn><!-- deeply nested complex subtree --></tagImNotInterestedIn>
    <person age="2">Eliezer</person>
</people>
```

When parsing with [the `people.hs` example from the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.2.0.2/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html), I get the following exception:

```
people.hs: XmlException {xmlErrorMessage = "Expected end tag for: Name {nameLocalName = \"people\", nameNamespace = Nothing, namePrefix = Nothing}", xmlBadInput = Just (EventBeginElement (Name {nameLocalName = "tagImNotInterestedIn", nameNamespace = Nothing, namePrefix = Nothing}) [])}
```

Basically, I'm looking for a way to ignore any tag (including all its children and attributes) except specific ones I specify parsers for. When using DOM-based parsers like HXT, this is obviously easy, but the [`tag` docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.2.0.2/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v:tag) explicitly states that it will fail unless all children are consumed.

The only hypothetical way I can think of accomplishing this is to use functions from `Control.Exception` to build up a Conduit with a `Maybe a` result (returning `Nothing` on exception) and then use `orE` to combine it with the parsers itself

Although it [has been stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375431/2597135) that the xml-conduit API needs some updating, I think there has to be a less-hackish way to ignore an entire subtree. Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: With a streaming parser you have to parse everything until you reach the close event of the the tag enclosing the current subtree. When you leave the inner parser of a `tag`, it expects to immediately parse the closing tag. Sadly the is no function for that in xml-conduit. One way to do it is to write a custom sink, count the opening tags (decrements on closing) and trash everything in between until the counter reach zero.

Comment: @Piezoid I have submitted a pull request that adds functions to perform this task. By using recursion, I didn't have to use a counter, even if that would be a possibility. I'll post an answer after it has been merged. Meanwhile, thanks for you support!

Comment: @UliKöhler did that PR ever land? Can you link to it?

Comment: @Flip Original PR https://github.com/snoyberg/xml/pull/40 but I didnt have time to 
finish it so pavelkogan stepped in and created https://github.com/snoyberg/xml/pull/58 which was merged

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.5.0 `Text.XML.Stream.Parse` provides a function [takeTree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.8.0/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v:takeTree), which probably could be used for the purpose.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Monad                (void)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class    (lift)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadThrow, runResourceT)
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy         (ByteString)
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8   (concat)
import           Data.Conduit                 (ConduitT, runConduit, (.|))
import           Data.Conduit.List            (mapM_)
import           Data.Text                    (Text, unpack)
import           Data.XML.Types               (Event)
import           Prelude                      hiding (concat, mapM_)
import           Text.XML.Stream.Parse        (choose, content, def,
                                               ignoreAnyTreeContent,
                                               ignoreAttrs, manyYield, many_,
                                               parseLBS, requireAttr, tag',
                                               tagNoAttr, takeTree)

data Person = Person Int Text deriving Show

parsePerson :: MonadThrow m => ConduitT Event o m (Maybe Person)
parsePerson = tag' "person" (requireAttr "age") $ \age -> do
    name <- content
    return $ Person (read $ unpack age) name

parsePeople :: MonadThrow m => ConduitT Event Person m ()
parsePeople = void $ tagNoAttr "people" $
  many_ (choose([takeTree "person" ignoreAttrs, ignoreAnyTreeContent])) .| manyYield parsePerson

persons :: ByteString
persons = concat [
    "<people>"
  , "<foo/>"
  , "<person age=\"25\">Michael</person>"
  , "<bar/>"
  , "<person age=\"2\">Eliezer</person>"
  , "<tagImNotInterestedIn>x</tagImNotInterestedIn>"
  , "</people>"

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $
  runConduit $ parseLBS def persons .| parsePeople .| mapM_ (lift . print)
```

The code above is based on [xml-conduit sample](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.8.0/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html). Only `parsePeople` is changed.

```
λ> main
Person 25 "Michael"
Person 2 "Eliezer"
```